# Android Fragment class variables not available from onOptionsItemSelected() method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-menu

I have a fragment inside Activity as below,

```
   public class ViewRecordFragment extends Fragment {

    private Integer recordId;

    public ViewRecordFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (recordId != null) {
            new ViewRecordActivity.GetRecordToDisplay(getActivity()).execute(recordId);
            loadImageResourcesAsync(recordId);
        }

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_record, container, false);
    }

    public static ViewRecordFragment newInstance(Integer recordId) {
        ViewRecordFragment fragment = new ViewRecordFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID, recordId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        return fragment;
    }

    private void loadImageResourcesAsync(Integer recordId) {
        new LoadImageResourcesAsync(getActivity()).execute(recordId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            recordId = getArguments().getInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_view_record, menu);
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_new_photo:

                //Integer recordId = getArguments().getInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CameraActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID, recordId);
                bundle.putString(BundleHelper.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and the activity uses this fragment to display a single record,

```
public class ViewRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private Integer recordId;
    private String patientNo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_record);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.header);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Record");

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            recordId = extras.getInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID);
            patientNo = extras.getString(BundleHelper.PATIENT_NO);
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("Patient Id: " + patientNo);
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            ViewRecordFragment viewRecordFragment = ViewRecordFragment.newInstance(recordId);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.view_record_fragment, viewRecordFragment
                    ).commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public static class GetRecordToDisplay extends GetRecordAsync {

        private TextView dos;
        private TextView facultyName;
        private TextView patientName;
        private TextView patientId;

        public GetRecordToDisplay(Activity activity) {
            super(activity);
            this.dos = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.date_submitted_text);
            this.facultyName = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            this.patientName = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.customer_name_text);
            this.patientId = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.customer_id_text);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Customer customer) {

            if (customer != null) {
                this.dos.setText(customer.getDOS_D());
                this.facultyName.setText(customer.getDOS_R());
                this.patientName.setText(customer.getCUSTOMER_N());
                this.patientId.setText(customer.getCUSTOMER_C());
            }
        }

    }
```

The problem happens when I try to start a new activity from a on menu item click. This `recordId` that I pass is null when click the menu item.

I an not sure what am I missing here. I can see that the `recordId` get assigned when creating the fragment inside the Activity(in the debug mode).

But when I click the menu item, and come to that particular menu item case, the `recordId` is null. But I am expecting the recordId that I assigned to it when I created the fragment.

Comment: according to the code you provided your `recordId` is null when you create a new fragment instance, so you pass `null` to arguments and thus it is `null` inside your fragment..

Comment: I am sorry I have not added the oncreate method. There I can see that this recordId get assigned and them passed into the fragment

Comment: Please pay attention to the code you post here.. you say that you have a `ViewRecordFragment` that has `onCreate` where you treat it as activity.. fragment doesn't have `getIntent()` method.. I think you've missed something while posting code here

Comment: Thanks Gennadii, I have added the complete code so that I will not miss anything. I still have the issue. Is there a particular way of passing variables to the fragment and preserve them in the fragment object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting arguments to your fragment but you are not using them. Do this in your fragment's `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    recordId = getArguments().getInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gennadii, I am setting it up in `newInstance()` method. as `fragment.setRecordId(recordId);`. I have done the same way. But I might have missed somethig. I will do it again and see :)

Comment: Don't do this:  `fragment.setRecordId(recordId)` because fragment will be recreated often on screen rotations and you will lose your value each time. Android provides arguments for this. If you set them, they are always available.

Comment: I added this into the code, But the problem still remains,  But I can see that onCreate, onViewCreated, methods are been executed twice before actually display the view

Comment: is `recordId` still null?

Comment: That's really weird, `recordId` value shouldn't be `null` if your activity receives it through `Intent`. Please make sure it is not `null` at this point: `ViewRecordFragment.newInstance(recordId);` Also put a breakpoint when you call `getArguments()` and take a look if the value is there.

Comment: I know this is weird. So, just when it hits the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_record);` it goes to the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods in Fragment. at the time `getArguments()` is `null`. Then when the fragment is replaced, it again executes, `onCreate` and `onCreateView`. There is all the necessary values. But again when I clicked menu item, the assigned `recordId` is null.

Comment: I used `int recId = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt(BundleHelper.RECORD_ID);` in the menu item case. which resolved the issue, But I am not sure what is the problem in my code and thank you for the help :)